# Run personalization rule programatically

Tags: content-search, personalization

I have built a custom peronsalization rule that sets a theme against a component. Each user can also choose a site theme which is stored against a contact.

I then want to use this logic to build up themed search results. So person in theme A will see search results A and so on.

Currently in the crawler I get all renderings I then parse the renderings 
rule.Condition as my custom rule which lets me get the theme. I then use the rule.Actions to get the datasource which lets me get the fields to be indexed.

This works when my rule is use datasource A for theme A and datasource B for theme B but I'm afraid it wont be robust with all rule combinations "hide", "except where" etc

Is there a way to use the sitecore's existing logic which determines what datasource to use given a personalisation rule?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this would work in your case, but previously i was able to run sitecore personalization rule by using this code to get the datasource (Sitecore 8.1):

```
public string GetPersonlizedRenderingDatasource(Rendering rendering, Item PageItem)
{
    var allReferences = GetRenderingsForControl(PageItem).ToList();
    var renderingUniqueId = ID.Parse(rendering.UniqueId);
    var renderingReferrence = allReferences.Where(i => ID.Parse(i.UniqueId).Equals(renderingUniqueId)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (renderingReferrence != null)
    {
       var ruleContext = new ConditionalRenderingsRuleContext(allReferences, renderingReferrence);

      renderingReferrence.Settings.Rules.RunFirstMatching(ruleContext);

      string personalizedDatasource = ruleContext.Reference.Settings.DataSource;
      return personalizedDatasource;
    }


 public RenderingReference[] GetRenderingsForControl(Item currentPageItem)
 {
     if (currentPageItem != null)
     {
         var device = Sitecore.Context.Device;
         DeviceItem deviceItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.Resources.Devices.GetAll().Where(d => d.Name.ToLower() == "default").First();
         var renderings = currentPageItem.Visualization.GetRenderings(device, true);
         return renderings;
     }
     return new RenderingReference[0];
  }
```

I don't think this would work if used in your custom Search crawler, But will work if it's run within user page context.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a play with that. Might have to swap out the device stuff

Comment: Yes you can just grab the context device object as well, if this solution works for you, please mark it as a selected answer.