# How do you programmatically determine which Profile Pattern has been applied to an individual rendering?

Tags: xdb, personalization

I want to provide the `Profile` and `Pattern Card` names for a particular rendering to global javascript variables on the front end.

How can I programmatically lookup these values from the personalisation rules applied to the rendering?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the C# portion of the code solution I came up with. Once you have the variables writing them into the rendered HTML is straight forward.

To use this just call one the methods `GetMatchedProfileName` or `GetMatchedPatternCardName` (code below). You can then write the resulting string into into your MVC model and render them in the view.

### Quick run through:

A) Get a reference to all the renderings on the page:

```
var allReferences = GetRenderingsForControl(contextItem, device).ToList();
```

B) Find the matching rendering reference:

```
var renderingReferrence = allReferences.Where(i => ID.Parse(i.UniqueId).Equals(renderingId)).FirstOrDefault();
```

C) Lookup the rule context and run the first matching rule:

```
var ruleContext = new ConditionalRenderingsRuleContext(allReferences, renderingReferrence);
renderingReferrence.Settings.Rules.RunFirstMatching(ruleContext);
```

D) Lookup the `datasource` that has been selected after running the rule.

```
string personalizedDatasource = ruleContext.Reference.Settings.DataSource;
```

e) The remaining code uses the method `GetMatchedProfile` to loop over the Actions and Conditions to obtain the matching condition. The matching condition contains the profile and pattern card name.

### Complete code:

```
public string GetMatchedProfileName(ID renderingId, Item contextItem, DeviceItem device)
{
    var ruleMatch = GetMatchedProfile(renderingId, contextItem, device);
    return ruleMatch.ProfileName;
}

public string GetMatchedPatternCardName(ID renderingId, Item contextItem, DeviceItem device)
{
    var ruleMatch = GetMatchedProfile(renderingId, contextItem, device);
    return ruleMatch.PatternName;
}

private HasPatternCondition<ConditionalRenderingsRuleContext> GetMatchedProfile(ID renderingId, Item contextItem, DeviceItem device)
{
    var allReferences = GetRenderingsForControl(contextItem, device).ToList();
    var renderingReferrence = allReferences.Where(i => ID.Parse(i.UniqueId).Equals(renderingId)).FirstOrDefault();
    var ruleContext = new ConditionalRenderingsRuleContext(allReferences, renderingReferrence);

    if (!ruleContext.Reference.Settings.Rules.Rules.Any())
        return null;

    renderingReferrence.Settings.Rules.RunFirstMatching(ruleContext);

    string personalizedDatasource = ruleContext.Reference.Settings.DataSource;

    var ruleMatch = GetMatchedProfile(ruleContext, personalizedDatasource);
    return ruleMatch;
}

private RenderingReference[] GetRenderingsForControl(Item contextItem, DeviceItem device)
{
    if (contextItem != null)
    {
        var renderings = contextItem.Visualization.GetRenderings(device, true);
        return renderings;
    }
    return new RenderingReference[0];
}

private HasPatternCondition<ConditionalRenderingsRuleContext> GetMatchedProfile(ConditionalRenderingsRuleContext ruleContext, string personalizedDatasource)
{
    foreach (var rule in ruleContext.Reference.Settings.Rules.Rules)
    {
        foreach (var action in rule.Actions)
        {
            var setDataSourceAction = action as SetDataSourceAction<ConditionalRenderingsRuleContext>;
            if (setDataSourceAction != null && setDataSourceAction.DataSource == personalizedDatasource)
            {
                var conditionMatch = rule.Condition as Sitecore.Analytics.Rules.Conditions.HasPatternCondition<ConditionalRenderingsRuleContext>;
                if (conditionMatch != null)
                {
                    return conditionMatch;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This answer uses some of the code from [Run personalization rule programatically](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11234/run-personalization-rule-programatically/11237#11237) to lookup rendering references.